# How $b>a \lor a \leq 0 \implies \max⁡(b,0)-\max⁡(\min⁡(a,b),0) \geq 0$?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, maxima-minima

*Disclaimer: I'm not a mathematician. I'm a developer (with physics degree).*

I'm programming tax form and stumbled on following (simplified) definition of one of the fields, lets name it P:
$$a = \dots$$
$$b = \dots$$
$$c = \max⁡(\min⁡(a,b),0)$$
$$
P = \left\{
    \begin{matrix}
        \max(b,0)-c & a \leq 0 \\
        \max(b,0)-c & b>a \\
        0 & otherwise &
    \end{matrix}
\right. \land P\geq0
$$

I've checked on [Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) that $\max(b,0)-c=\max(b,0)-\max⁡(\min⁡(a,b),0)$ always meets the required conditions.

[$\max(b,0)-\max⁡(\min⁡(a,b),0) \geq 0$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=max%E2%81%A1%28b%2C0%29-max%E2%81%A1%28min%E2%81%A1%28a%2Cb%29%2C0%29%3E%3D0) results in $True$ (which I'm assuming means that it's always true)
and
[$\max(b,0)-\max⁡(\min⁡(a,b),0) > 0$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=max%E2%81%A1%28b%2C0%29-max%E2%81%A1%28min%E2%81%A1%28a%2Cb%29%2C0%29%3E0) have following solutions:
$${a > 0, b > a}$$
$${a <= 0, b > 0}$$
which means that initial conditions are met.

So seems that I just need to type in my program that $P = \max(b,0)-c$ and assume that task is finished, but I'm curious: **How can one come from definition of $P$ to $P = \max(b,0)-c$?**
How can one get rid of all conditions (ifs) and end up with one simple formula $\max(b,0)-c$?

I've tried to start with something like this:

1. $a \leq 0 \implies a=\min(a,0)$
2. $b>a \implies b=max(a,b)$

and for each case somehow end up with $\max(b,0)-c\geq0$ but all my attempts failed so far.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm probably asking for a proof that:
$${
{P = 
\left\{
    \begin{matrix}
        \max(b,0)-c & a \leq 0 \\
        \max(b,0)-c & b>a \\
        0 & otherwise &
    \end{matrix}
\right. \land P\geq0}
} \implies \max(b,0)-c\geq0
$$

---

Edit: Better explanation for what I'm asking for:

In ["Material for the course Constructive Logic at Carnegie Mellon University" (15-317)](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Efp/courses/15317-f00/handouts/logic.pdf) I have found folowing example how we prove $A \lor B$

> If we know that A ∨ B is true, we must consider two cases: A true and
> B true. If we can prove a conclusion C true in both cases, then C must
> be true! Written as an inference rule:

$$
\frac
{
\begin{matrix} \\  \\ A \lor B \, true \end{matrix}
\begin{matrix}\frac{}{A\,true}u \\ \vdots \\ C\,true \end{matrix}
\begin{matrix}\frac{}{B\,true}w \\ \vdots \\ C\,true \end{matrix}
}{C\,true} \lor E^{u,w}
$$

Translated to my case it's (assuming I correctly understand how inference rules are written):
$$
\frac
{
\begin{matrix} \\  \\ a \leq 0 \lor b>a \, true \end{matrix}
\begin{matrix}\frac{}{a \leq 0 \, true}u \\ \vdots \\ \max(b,0)-c \geq 0 \,true \end{matrix}
\begin{matrix}\frac{}{b>a \, true}w \\ \vdots \\ \max(b,0)-c \geq 0 \,true \end{matrix}
}{\max(b,0)-c \geq 0 \,true} \lor E^{u,w}
$$

And I want to know what hides behind every $\vdots$

Answer (score 1):

You can separate the cases.

**Case 1:** $a\leq 0$.

If $a\leq 0$, then you know that $\min(a,b)\leq 0$, which means that $\max(\min(a,b),0)=0$.

You also know that $\max(b,0)\geq 0$, which means that $$\max(b,0)+\max(\min(a,b),0) = \max(b,0)+0=\max(b,0)\geq 0.$$

**Case 2**: $a>0$.

In this case, because we know that $b>a\lor a\leq 0$, we know that $b>a$.

Therefore, we know that $\min(a,b)=a$, which means that $\max(\min(a,b),0) = \max(a,0)=a$, because $a>0$.

This means that

$$\max(b,0)-\max(\min(a,b),0)=\max(b,0)-a=b-a,$$
and since we know $b>a$, we also know $b-a>0$, which means the entire expression is positive in this case.

---

If you want to fully write out the range of values that the expression $\max(b,0)-\max(\min(a,b),0)$ can take, then you need to separate out some more cases. In particular, you have the following $6$ cases:

$$\max(b,0)-\max(\min(a,b),0)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if}&a\leq b\leq 0\\
b&\text{if}&a\leq 0\leq b\\
0&\text{if}&b\leq a \leq 0\\
0&\text{if}&b\leq 0\leq a\\
b-a&\text{if}&0\leq a\leq b\\
0&\text{if}&0\leq b\leq a\end{cases}$$

This also shows that the expression is *always* positive (i.e., not only when $b<a\lor a\leq 0$).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe I was not clear but I'm asking for a step by step algorithm how from b>a ∨ a≤0 I can end up with max(b,0)−c. So that I can learn how to write such proofs as functions in programming language with types.

Comment: @SeeR I don't understand your question then. There is no single value of $c$ such that $\max(b,0)-\max(\min(a,b),0)=\max(b,0)-c$. The value of $c$ will depend on $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I mean, I want to learn how to write a programming function body with signature more or less like: P ProofThatPCanBeDrivedFrom(ALessThanB x, ALessThanEq0 y). P, ALessThanB  and ALessThanEq0 are types. Of course I don't expect to get a program as an answer on math stackexchange, that's why I'm asking for a proof algorithm. How can I start from b>a ∨ a≤0 (input) and end in max(b,0)−max(min(a,b),0)≥0 (output)

Comment: @SeeR You can start from $b>a \lor a\leq 0$ as input, then analyze the two cases I analyze in my answer, and you get the output that the inequality is true.